# Chance of obtaining fish element Probability

Tags: javascript, random, probability

I'm trying to get the percentage of getting some fish.
`X` is the unique number here, it's between 0-99, but in my example code it's 70, for test purposes.

But currently it returns really wrong results, so I'm doing something wrong here.

Current output:

```
[-0.17142857142857143, 0.04285714285714286, 0.2571428571428571, 0.2714285714285714]
```

Which means

- -17% to get `fish1`,
- 4.2% for `fish2`,
- 25.7% `fish3`,
- 27% `fish4`.

The correct math is as follows:

If X number is 82+, it will get fish 1.
If X number is 67+, it's fish 2 (unless 82+ etc).
If x number is 52+ it's fish 3.
if it's 51 or less, it's fish 4.

So, in theory, with a `x` of 85, its a 3/85 chance of obtaining it.

Then I need the probability by the current X of getting that specific fish. 
What am I doing wrong here?

```js
function fishesPercentage(X) {
  var NumberSelected = RandomNumber(0,X-1);
  NumberSelected = 70;
  console.log("RANDOOM NUMBER IS : ",NumberSelected);
  let Fish1 = NumberSelected - 82;
  let Fish2 = NumberSelected - 67;
  let Fish3 = NumberSelected - 52;
  let Fish4 = NumberSelected - 51;

  return [
    Fish1/ NumberSelected,
    Fish2/ NumberSelected,
    Fish3/ NumberSelected,
    Fish4/ NumberSelected
  ];
}
```

Comment: what does a negative probability mean?

Comment: @NinaScholz that its unobtainable. like 82+ its getting fish1, but since numberselected is 70, its not possible.

Comment: what values do you expect with `70`? i have a problme, because 70 is just a result, and does not work for getting a probability, becaus you have already the probability for 4 values/fishes.

Comment: i would expect @NinaScholz atleast 51% of fish4 atleast. with fish 4 it would be 51/70, and fish 2 would be 3/70 chance.

Comment: please if you can be more precise, what is X what is the probability of P of getting fish 1 given some X, etc... Right now, your problem is so unclear that we are forced to guess.... You say: in theory "x of 85, its a 3/85 chance of obtaining it.". What does *it* refer to? fish1? if yes, why 3/85 ? why not 2/85? Also if x is 85, is the probability of getting fish2 0 (and 0 as well for fish3 and fish 4)

Comment: with a value of `70`, you have no probability anymore you have a distinct value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the probabilities of obtaining fishes 1 to 4 for a given number `X`, and a series of ranges. The total number of fishes is:

Fish 4) 51 or X (if X is lower)

Fish 3) 68-51 o X-51 (if X is lower than 68)

etc.

If any of these X-N is negative, that means that there are no fishes of that type.

This could be achieved with any of the two functions below:

```
function fishProb(x) {
    let fish4 = Math.max(Math.min(x, 51),0)
    let fish3 = Math.max(Math.min(x-51, 68-51),0)
    let fish2 = Math.max(Math.min(x-68, 82-68),0)
    let fish1 = Math.max(Math.min(x-82, 99-82),0)
    return([fish1, fish2, fish3, fish4].map(f => f/x))
}

function fishProb2(x) {
    var allFishes = x
    var fishType = [51, 68-51, 82-68, 99-82]
    var fishes = []
    for (const currentFishes of fishType) {
        fishes.push( Math.max(Math.min(allFishes, currentFishes), 0) )
        allFishes -= currentFishes
    }
   return(fishes.map(f => f/x).reverse())
}
```

Both functions return the same thing. The second one I think expresses the problem in a simpler way.

If you have X=70 then you have 51 Fish4, from the remaining 70-51 you have (68-51) of Fish3, and the other 3 remaining are Fish2. No Fish1 are in the lot.

```
//X = 70
[0, 0.02857142857142857, 0.24285714285714285, 0.7285714285714285]

//X = 85
[0.03529411764705882, 0.16470588235294117, 0.2, 0.6]

//X = 20. In this case you only have 20 Fish4 and none of the others.
[0, 0, 0, 1]
```

Comment: Yes, should change the names accordingly. Names changed and added a reverse() for the second one.

Comment: The `reverse()` can be removed is an `unshift` is used instead of the `push`